# Datasource avanced properties

Tags: grails

I just wondering is this is a valid DataSource configuration:

```
development {
        properties {
            maxActive = 50
            maxIdle = 25
            minIdle = 5
            initialSize = 8
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1000 * 15 * 60
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1000 * 15 * 60
            maxWait = 10000
            validationQuery = "/* ping */"
        }
        dataSource {
            username = "test"
            password = "test"
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://params"
        }

    }
```

If i have this, do the dataSource use the properties listed above?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to centralize your properties, you can define the datasource without an enviornment first:

```
dataSource {
  properties {
  }
}

development {
  dataSource {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`properties` is part of the `datasource` bean (of type [BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html)). Using DSL makes it easier not to use the accessor methods explicitly to set/get the members.

So I think you have to stick to

```
development{
   dataSource{
      ......
      properties{
         .......
      }
   }
}
```